# what's the difference between call by value and call by rvalue reference in vector.push_back(const & T val) before c++11

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference, call-by-value

Since rvalue references were not supported before C++11, there were no move constructors. The `const T&` arguments makes it use the copy constructor even for temporaries, which is the same as calling the copy constructor via a *by-value* argument? `std::vector`'s `void push_back(const T& Val)` allows `Val` to receive the right value, so why not pass it by value?

The other question is: Why can `const T&` receive right values?

Comment: I tried to rephrase the question as-best I understood it. I hope I didn't destroy it for you.

Comment: And if I understand it correctly, taking it by value would imply always making _two_ copies instead of one.

Comment: 'when template T is int'
 
vector::push_back(const int& num){//befror c++11, call copy constructor, assign 1 to num(is that right?)
 
     ...//after c++11, call move constructor make it cost less

 }
 
vector::push_back(int num){//call by value
 
     ...

 }
 
vector<int> v;
 
v.push_back(1);// is assignment via copy constructor the same cost as call by value? if it's same, why not use the second way?

Comment: I understand, thanks for your answer. if it's call by value, first call copy constructor ：assign 1 to num, then second call copy constructor ：Constructs the parameter copy to the tail of the data container  ； if call by reference it will just call one time copy constructor to assign 1 to num.

Comment: When you have fundamental types it would probably be better to take them by value but it also need to work well with bigger user- or implementation-defined types, like `std::string`.